# How to print footer at the first and last pages in iReport 5.6.0?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to print the footer only in the first and last pages. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "Page Footer" band with "PrintWhenExpression" set to

```
$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1
```

for first page, and "Last Page Footer" band for last page.